# windows.requestFileSystem is undefined using latest Cordova

Tags: cordova

I have been trying to get window.requestFileSystem to work using Cordova 3.5, and I have had no luck.  My whole experience with Cordova has been terrible - I've spent more time working around bad builds and configuration issues than getting an app built!

I can make a call to the device plugin and get the UUID.  Next I want to write a file, using various code examples, but I can't even get past this first step:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, this.gotFS_init, this.fail);
```

Why would this not work, if I have the deviceready state as true?  I have also added IOS references to the file plugin in the config.xml, per Cordova's website instructions.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show the relevant parts of your config.xml? Does it work if you use `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY`?

Comment: `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'LocalFileSystem' is undefined` - using Windows 10

Comment: Same error with `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY`